# Collect answer and test it

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to do a scavenger hunt with my students. Basically they do something, input an answer, if it is correct then the page should give them the URL to jump to the next clue. If it is wrong, they get a "Sorry, wrong" message and can keep inputting until they get it. I have read several sites and tried different things. I had the input worked out, but could not figure out how to display a hotlink for them to click on in JS. I have a free site setup and want to insert this Javascript but of course it is not working!

```js
function myFunction() {
  var letter = document.getElementById("personsInput").value;
  var text;
  let linkName = "Next challenge.";
  // If the word is correct “chocolate"
  if (letter === "chocolate") {
    text = "<a ref ='https:// this is where the URL goes'> +linkName + " < /a>";
    // If the word is anything else
  } else {
    text = "Sorry, wrong answer";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<input id="personsInput" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">What is your answer?</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: The browser console is indicating a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to do it
Using document.createElement

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {
  const answer = document.getElementById("personsInput").value;
  const resultArea = document.getElementById("demo")
  const linkName = "Next challenge.";
  const wrongAnswer = "Sorry, wrong answer.";
  resultArea.innerHTML = '';

  if (answer === "chocolate") {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'http://google.com';
    link.text = linkName;
    link.target = '_blank';
    resultArea.appendChild(link);
   } else {
    text = "Sorry, wrong answer";
    resultArea.innerHTML = wrongAnswer;
   }
  }
</script>
<input id="personsInput" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">What is your answer?</button>
<p id="demo">
</p>
```

As noted in the other answers maybe this is not the best way to exam your students, as they can view the source and get the correct answers from there.

Comment: Thank you.  This is great.  I was trying to use this approach before but gave up and tried to do something that was more simple.  But this opens the new page in a new window, which is what I was looking for.  This is a big help.  Again, not an exam.  This is for fun - students will work in teams and on their phones to do a scavenger hunt around the campus.  Hopefully they will have fun.  Much appreciated. I owe you a beer too.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are missing the closing quotation around `"<a ...> + linkname`
2. Your anchor tag needs `href`, not `ref`. I fixed these two issues and it works as intended.

```html
<input id="personsInput" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">What is your answer?</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var letter = document.getElementById("personsInput").value;
        var text;
        let linkName = "Next challenge.";
        // If the word is correct “chocolate"
        if (letter === "chocolate") {
            text = "<a href ='https:// this is where the URL goes'>" +linkName + "</a>";
        // If the word is anything else
        } else {
            text = "Sorry, wrong answer";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I was so close.  I owe you a beer.

Comment: @Cam You're welcome. If this was helpful, feel free to mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You Got it! You are just missing a closing " after where the URL goes.

A warning your students will be able to inspect the site source and see the correct answers.

```
text = "<a ref ='https:// this is where the URL goes'>" + linkName + "
 </a>";
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var letter = document.getElementById("personsInput").value;
  var text;
  let linkName = "Next challenge.";
  // If the word is correct “chocolate"
  if (letter === "chocolate") {
    text = "<a ref ='https:// this is where the URL goes'>" + linkName + " </a>";
    // If the word is anything else
  } else {
    text = "Sorry, wrong answer";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<input id="personsInput" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">What is your answer?</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is very helpful.   Yes, some of the students could probably view the code, but it isn't for a test. I am having them do a scavenger hunt around our campus to build team spirit and to get them acquainted with the services and buildings.    Most of them will probably use their phones too - which may make it harder to view the code.  Not sure.  But I doubt they will do it.  It is just for fun anyway.